# (Animation Nodes) How can I make objects rotate to face the direction of the normals of a mesh?

Tags: animation-nodes

I'm trying to recreate Mystique's transformations from the new X-men movies, and I cant figure out how to get the directions of individual polygons or vertices. I can get the location and "normal," but the normal vector doesn't seem to correspond to any sort of rotation. Help?

Comment: Please illustrate "*Mystique's transformations from the new X-men movies*" not everyone is familiar with what you want to achieve. Please edit your question and provide some reference images and what you have done so far and why it failed.

Answer (score 4):

Use an Object Mesh Data node to get the face data of the target object. Connect the Polygons output to an Object Instancer and create a loop subprogram that has a polygon and an object iterator. With the Mesh data node selected you can press <kbd>W</kbd> and choose polygons to create the loop and add another object list iterator to it.

For the subprogram, connect the object to an Object Transform Output and use a Polygon Info node to get the location and normal of each face. Connecting the polygon normal to the object rotation input will create a Direction to Rotation node that gives the direction you want. The center output will give you the location to place each instance.

[image: example result]

[image: object rotation]

Comment: I realize my problem is that I forgot to check all the boxes in the transform output node. I feel stupid now.

Comment: @sambler Can you help me with this question please? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/163003/animation-nodes-how-to-make-an-object-face-camera-yet-let-the-object-rotate-ar